# Externally authenticate user within PAM session/PAM session within PAM session

Tags: authentication, pam

Is there a way of properly authenticating a user from within a custom PAM session?

I am currently writing my own PAM authentication module which allows the user to login via an external token. This token has to be generated before the user can login with my module. Therefore I would like to fall back to default PAM authentication when no token exists and continue with my code as soon as the user is authenticated.

Is this possible somehow? In pseudo-code my module looks like this:

```
pam_sm_authenticate() {
  if (first_login) {
    code_copied_from_pam_unix_to_authenticate_user();
    // do something else here?
  } else {
    custom_auth();
  }
}
```

As a quick fix, I copied the code from Linux's pam_unix module into my own and it works.
However, this is not very satisfactory as it incurs a lot of additional libraries and
also will only work as long as pam_unix doesn't change. I would prefer opening another
PAM session within my session but haven't got it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let your code carry out all the logic: use PAM and its configuration first to make sure your module runs in the best conditions (ie. does not require copying `pam_unix`'s code).

First, let me suggest another pseudo code for your module:

```
pam_sm_authenticate() {
    if (first_login) return PAM_CRED_INSUFFICIENT;
    else custom_auth();
}
```

Here, I consider *first login* to be a case of credentials insufficiency.  I'm telling PAM that the module is failing because it doesn't have everything it needs to fully authenticate the user. Now, assuming your module is called `my_module`, a possible configuration would be:

```
auth [cred_insufficient=ok success=done default=2] my_module.so
auth [success=ok default=1]      pam_unix.so
auth sufficient                  my_module.so
auth requisite                   pam_deny.so
```

Here are the details:

- First, the request goes through `my_module`. Several possibilities here:

  1. First login: your module returned `PAM_CRED_INSUFFICIENT`. This case is *caught* by PAM (through `cred_insufficient`), in which case it is configured to mark the chain as successful (`ok`) but to **keep going**.
  2. This wasn't the first login, you went through `custom_auth()` and it was a success (it returned `PAM_SUCCESS`). In this case, we put an end to the chain (`done`) : **access granted**.
  3. This wasn't the first login, and `custom_auth()` didn't end up well (`PAM_AUTH_ERR` or other kinds of internal errors). In this case, skip the next 2 lines (`default=2`). The chain goes right into `pam_deny`, which always fails: **access denied**.
- In the first scenario, the chain goes on to `pam_unix`. Two possibilities here:

  1. UNIX authentication succeeds. This marks the chain as successful (`ok`) and **goes on to the next module**.
  2. UNIX authentication fails. The next module is skipped (`default=1`), and the chain ends in `pam_deny`: **access denied**.
- If you reach the third line, it means that `my_module` ended with `PAM_CRED_INSUFFICIENT` the first time, and that `pam_unix` succeeded. Your module is called again (`// do something else here?`) as `sufficient`. Two possibilities again:

  1. This time, your module succeeds: **access granted**.
  2. The module fails again, but for another reason than credentials insufficiency: **access denied**.

You might also want to execute custom code *after UNIX authentication*, even if it failed. In order to do that, change the second line to:

```
auth [success=ok default=bad]    pam_unix.so
```

This will make the chain go through `my_module` another time no matter what, but the chain will be marked as *failed*. Even if your module ends up successful here, the chain will fail.

You might also want to make your module aware of how many times we've called it in a chain: distinguish the first call to `my_module` from the second one. This could be done easily with arguments:

```
auth [cred_insufficient=ok success=done default=2] my_module.so
auth [success=ok default=1]      pam_unix.so
auth sufficient                  my_module.so second_time
auth requisite                   pam_deny.so
```

Here, the second call to `pam_sm_authenticate` will be passed an argument (through `argv` and `argc`) which should help you *locate* your module in the chain at runtime. Of course, your `firstLogin` condition should be enough to make such a distinction.